# Why do I get **No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present** error when accessing Google Places API

Tags: angular, google-places-api

I'm getting JSON data from Google Places API through a service in Angular 4. When I hit the API endpoint in browser it returns the JSON data but getting the same data via Http in Angular gives this "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present" error. This happens with Wikpedia API also.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try one thing for testing purpose:

Download this plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

This will solve error for time being. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the API for server-side libraries. Try using the  [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)